# Deployment of Access SQL database to SQL Server

Tags: html, sql-server, database, ms-access

I know I'm asking quite a large question in scale here, but I'm looking more for some general guidelines.

At my work, I have the skeleton of an MS Access database that is ~50% completed. The scope of the project, however, is growing larger and larger as we plan for it more.

I am comfortable in HTML/CSS and Javascript, but have never done any SQL Server back end type stuff - but my question is: what is the process of deploying this access database to an online database? What are some guidelines, links, or guidebooks I can look into for this?

Comment: Did you find either of the answers useful? It'd be great if you could put closure to your question by accepting an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely check out the upsizing wizard information on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924.

Use the upsizing wizard with a test SQL Server instance and see how it works. If you need a different tool, SQL Server's import/export tool will work great to migrate your databases over to SQL Server. Use this documentation for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

There are many YouTube videos that you can watch prior to migrating to SQL Server also: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=migrate+access+to+sql+server&page=&utm_source=opensearch

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server has an import functionality that allows you to import from other ODBC drivers, text files (csv), and Access.  If you have access to the SQL Server management studio then you'll be able to do this.  If not, then you can always download the express version locally,  import your access file, then export (dump) your sql server database, and then upload/import it to your server.

My recommendation, if you see yourself expanding away from Access then do it now rather than later.  You will most likely run into minor details to fix which are better off sorting early than later in the project when it's close to release.   The express version should help with local development.